# Is there a Scoville scale for "coldness" (e.g. mint)?

Tags: chili-peppers, mint, capsaicin

Certain foods taste hot like peppers and are measured by the Scoville scale. Some foods also taste "cold". Mint is the main one that comes to mind. Is there a similar scale for this kind of taste?

If there isn't (or maybe even if there is) is there any reason we couldn't just use the same methodology as we do with the Scoville scale?

Comment: Are there any other foods than those which contain 'menthol' which do this? I can't think of any. [& bizarrely, menthol is just as much an irritant as capsaicin.]

Comment: @Tetsujin some of the sugar alcohols, especially [erythritol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythritol) actually absorb heat when dissolved, giving a cooling effect. Not quite the same, but a similar sensation

Comment: @Tetsujin Urea as well, although not commonly used, but in for example https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ischoklad

Comment: The Scoville scale is (at least originally) defined by the amount of sugar required to neutralize the 'heat'.  I don't believe this methodology would work with mint.  Is there is some substance that neutralizes mint flavor?

Comment: @JimmyJames I thought it was sugar-water. So even if sugar doesn't help neutralize the coldness, the concentration of the menthol (or other active ingredient if we're talking about something other than mint) will be reduced which will also reduce the effect of the mint right?

Comment: Yes the sugar is mixed in water along with the test sample but it's the sugar that is doing the neutralizing.  The more contemporary approach is to measure the compounds directly and then convert to Scoville units.  We just don't have a corresponding historical methodology for mint, it seems.

Comment: You may find something in Ayurvedic medicine. Mint and cucumber would be 'cool' to neutralize a hot meridian energy channel.  Scollvile depends on the concentration of the chemical capsaicin, with a maximum of 16M. You would need to find a common chemical which causes a sensation of 'cold'.

Comment: Also, solid coconut fat does the same thing....

Comment: @ViktorMellgren "in industrial production, urea is often added" - lovely

Comment: Black pepper has piperine and uses Scoville. Ginger has Gingerol and uses Scoville. Garlic and onions use the pyruvate scale.  Mustard, Horseradish, and Wasabi have an oil called Allyl Isothiocyanate but don't seem to have a scale.  http://scottroberts.org/is-there-a-pungency-scale-for-garlic-horseradish-wasabi-mustard-onions-cinnamon-and-black-pepper/

Answer (score 35):

There are thermal sensation scales, and they are applied in food research too, although their primary use tends to be focused on clothing or environment. They tend to be categorical rather than ratio scales, and don't depend on the presence of a single compound the way scoville does. Despite checking several likely sources (a book on neurogastronomy, a thesis on measuring the perception of food - mostly focused on texture, but also discussing thermoreceptors) I didn't find a mention of a specific culinary scale that measures menthol concentration.

Instead of a specialized scale, industrial users of menthol products seem to simply use the relative menthol content, such as selling an essential oil that with "60% menthol". And the general public doesn't seem to have created a cult around menthol content the way it has done for capsaicine content - personally, I know more people who care for the scoville number of the chilli they are eating than people who can tell the difference between spearmint and apple mint.

I suspect that, while creating such a scale is possible, nobody has bothered to. And even if some food scientist did do it, it doesn't seem to have caught on, especially outside of professional circles.

Comment: Plus 1. Likely the variety of mints is not so broad as in the case of hot peppers. Plus capsaicin might indeed drive consumers in a kind of "addiction", and have strong effect already with natural peppers. This motivated the special interest, but it is just an opinion.

Comment: I think a big reason for the popularity of the Scoville scale is the bragging rights associated with tolerating high values as a personal achievement. Menthol doesn't inspire the same excitement because even the highest possible concentration doesn't have as dramatic an effect as capsaicin does.

Comment: There is something of a "cult around menthol", mainly due to its inclusion in many cigarettes rather than food.  Not being a smoker, I'm not sure if people categorize the "mentholicity" of any given brand over another, but there's at least something there.

Comment: @barbecue True, but licking a menthol crystal is still quite strong.

Answer (score 5):

Scoville's original method for determinig the Scoville level of a pepper was to dry the pepper, extract the heat components, and continunally dilute the extract until the majority of a panel of tasters could no longer detect it. It's not a great test, but could easily be adapted to any sort of sensation.

In the case of menthol, the majority of menthol in any detectable concentration that we encounter is added artificially so the exact menthol content is known.

Answer (score 0):

The Scoville scale is a measurement of the pungency (spiciness or "heat") of chili peppers, as recorded in Scoville Heat Units (SHU), based on the concentration of capsaicinoids.

You can find a list with the concentration of menthol in plants given in ppm. Here is a list I found on https://www.naturalmedicinefacts.info/chemical/17003.html. This is a type of scale that is similar to the Scoville scale, although it doesn't use human sensation as one of the criteria.

Mentha pulegium
found in Shoot
max 478,000 ppm

Helianthus annuus
sunflower
found in Flower
max 310,000 ppm

Mentha arvensis var. piperascens
found in Leaf
max 24,385 ppm

Mentha x piperita subsp. nothosubsp. piperita
found in Leaf
max 20,000 ppm

Mentha spicata
spearmint
found in Leaf
max 15,000 ppm

Mentha aquatica
bergamot mint, eau-de-cologne mint, lemon mint, orange mint, water mint
found in Shoot, Leaf
max 3,570 ppm

Micromeria fruticosa
found in Leaf
max 3,030 ppm

Pycnanthemum virginianum
Virginia mountain-mint, Virginia-thyme, wild basil
found in Shoot
max 3,016 ppm

Pelargonium graveolens
rose geranium, rose-scent geranium
found in Plant
max 1,852 ppm

Satureja parvifolia
found in Shoot
max 1,010 ppm

Hedeoma pulegioides
American false pennyroyal, American pennyroyal
found in Plant, Pollen Or Spore
max 1,000 ppm

Pycnanthemum incanum
hoary mountain-mint
found in Shoot
max 798 ppm

Pycnanthemum pilosum
hairy mountain-mint
found in Flower, Leaf
max 700 ppm

Mentha longifolia
Biblical mint, horse mint, silver mint, wild mint
found in Shoot
max 620 ppm

Pycnanthemum tenuifolium
narrow-leaf mountain-mint
found in Shoot
max 620 ppm

Artemisia dracunculus
French tarragon, Russian tarragon, silky wormwood, tarragon, wild tarragon
found in Shoot
max 500 ppm

Pycnanthemum muticum
blunt mountain-mint, clustered mountain-mint
found in Shoot
max 450 ppm

Satureja grandiflora
greater calamint, large-flower calamint, mint-savory, showy calamint, showy-savory
found in Shoot
max 420 ppm

Sideritis scardica
found in Shoot
max 370 ppm

Calamintha nepeta
lesser calamint
found in Plant
max 290 ppm

Minthostachys mollis
found in Shoot
max 215 ppm

Pycnanthemum clinopodioides
found in Shoot
max 176 ppm

Pycnanthemum beadlei
found in Shoot
max 140 ppm

Micromeria fruticosa subsp. barbata
found in Shoot
max 105 ppm

Mentha x rotundifolia

found in Leaf
max 80 ppm
33475
Micromeria thymifolia
found in Leaf
max 45 ppm

Ocimum basilicum
basil, sweet basil
found in Essential Oil, Plant
max 32 ppm

Pycnanthemum montanum
found in Shoot
max 32 ppm

Juniperus communis
common juniper, dwarf juniper, juniper, malchangel, mountain juniper, prostrate juniper
found in Fruit
max 22 ppm

Elytrigia repens
couch grass, coutch, dog grass, quack grass, quick grass, scutch, twitch grass
found in Plant, Rhizome
max 20 ppm

Hedeoma drummondii
New Mexico pennyroyal
found in Plant
max 10 ppm

Acinos suaveolens
found in Shoot
max 3 ppm

Calamintha nepeta subsp. glandulosa
lesser calamint
found in Leaf
max 1 ppm

Rheum palmatum
Chinese rhubarb, ornamental rhubarb
found in Rhizome
max 1 ppm

Comment: Please always cite your sources - see [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for details. Answers that fail to meet the requirements listed in the linked Help Center chapter will be removed.